# Fetch Value of hyperlink in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have one hyperlink and i need to findout the value of one field.
I am sharing the below code

**Code**:

```
url="http://localhost/Employee/EmployeeMgmt/EmpDetails.aspx?

EmpId=784657&From=Information Technology";
```

Now, I need to fetch the value of `EmpId=784657`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** with regex **[`\bEmpId=(\d+)&`](https://regex101.com/r/gP2kC6/2)**. You can get the capturing group value from result using index `1`

```js
var url = "http://localhost/Employee/EmployeeMgmt/EmpDetails.aspx?EmpId=784657&From=Information Technology";

console.log(url.match(/\bEmpId=(\d+)&/i)[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var url="http://localhost/Employee/EmployeeMgmt/EmpDetails.aspx?EmpId=784657&From=Information Technology",
    empid = /\bEmpId=(\d+)/.exec(url)[1]
```

empid is the string "784657"

The little `\b` there guards you against a SimilarEmpId variable.  [decodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) and may also be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually getting query string of url. Try this pure javascript code

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

To retrieve particular query string

```
var empId = getParameterByName('EmpId');
```

Check this [Getting Query String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: If you're going to copy this, link to it.  The comments are useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

please try:

```
 function search(url,param) {
        var params = url.split("?")[1].split("&");
        for (i in params) {
            var key = params[i].split("=")[0];
            if (key == param) {
                return params[i].split("=")[1];
            }
        }
        return "not found";
    }
```